# Error opening directory “/media/" Permission denied... virtualbox

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, lubuntu

I'm running Lubuntu on Virtualbox on a PC.   I've shared a folder (via the Lubuntu menu) on my PC so that I can transfer files to and from my Lubuntu instance.

However, when I try opening it I get the following error:

> Error opening directory “/media/sf_MOVIES_AND_SERIES”: Permission denied.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: add your user to the vboxfs group

Comment: if MOVIES_AND_SERIES directory is also mount point on host OS, try to change shared folder path into a directory in MOVIES_AND_SERIES.

Answer (score 5):

> Any ideas?

Check help

> For Linux and Oracle Solaris guests, access is restricted to members of
>   the group vboxsf

Add user to vboxsf group

```
sudo adduser <username> vboxsf
```

Comment: That gave some sort of an error ( I don't remember what exactly), so I continued looking and this worked:  
sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a username 

ln -s /media/sf_shared/ name_of_link.

Comment: @Gottano after running `sudo adduser myUserName vboxsf`, I restarted the VM and it worked for me.